# Can I use span element as container

Tags: html

I would like to ask you about span element. What I want to do is that I have some structure of html document with various div elements and I would like to wrap these div elements into span elements. Is it the correct use of span in these case ? Because I dont want affect visual of the existing page and I need to create unique IDs for these divs but some of them already have ID and I cant change it, therefore I use these wrapping but is it correct use ? Or span should be used inside like paragraphs to apply some style for text ? Thank you Krpo

Comment: Block level elements can't be children of inline elements, so nope, `<span>` is almost certainly not the right choice for whatever you want to do. A `<div>` (or maybe one of the "new" semantic elements like `<section>`) would be the more obvious choice, why does it have to be an inline element?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to wrap these div elements into span elements

This is [forbidden by the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element).

> Content model: Phrasing content.

The [list of phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) elements does not include div

> a abbr area (if it is a descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins kbd label link (if it is allowed in the body) map mark MathML math meter noscript object output picture progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong sub sup SVG svg template textarea time u var video wbr text

---

You should probably use another div instead.